# How to get coordinates from non-GPS GNSS like GLONASS with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, gps

I'm using React-Native to create a native application for Android platforms. I want to get the coordinates from [Global navigation satellite systems(GNSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation) like GPS, GLONASS, Compass, IRNSS, QZSS, Galileo. For GPS I can use [react-native geolocation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) but for others, I don't know what I should do.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Android does not have separate APIs based on the source of the location data. Any React Native plugin would use `LocationManager`, or possibly Play Services' location APIs, and those would use whatever location capabilities are built into the device. For external receivers, you would need to contact the manufacturers of those receivers and ask them what sort of Android integration options they offer.

Comment: Take a look in Fused API and https://github.com/MustansirZia/react-native-fused-location

Comment: @CommonsWare. Thanks for your answer. I searched a lot and found that there is a PRN code which would show me what is satellite system. But I should use java insted of react-native and javascript to create my app. Is there a way to get that PRN code with react-native.

Comment: @Mate .thanks too. I couldn't understand  how Fused API can help me to find the coordinates based on each satellite system seperately.

Comment: Almost three years later, has anyone found out another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. 
Not only it is not possible on react-native but also it is relate to version of Android that the phone is using.
Acording to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095702/6771718
**"With the andvent of Android 7.1, the raw data from GPS chips will be available to developers."**
I want to compute coordinate separately. So i need to get raw data from GNSS sensor. For react-native in the time of writing this answer there was no module to get raw data for new Android phones. but it is possible by means of Android native programming with Java.